# How to input multiple keys in terminal to output multiple values in hashmap java

Tags: for-loop, foreach, hashmap, key, return-value

Program Overview: The terminal asks the user 'Whats wrong' and the user gives a word 'bug' (which is a key! from the hashmap)if it's a key then it outputs the corresponding 'value' from the hashmap in the terminal screen, else it it gives a random defaultresponse instead.

The problem: if the user puts 'bug and crash' it will only read the key 'bug' and output's the corresponding value but what i want for it do is to pick up more than 1 key word and output the  corresponding values, how would i do that?

Here is the code that you need for the 2 classes.

A method from the test class

```
   public HashMap<String, String> createresponseMap(){

   HashMap<String,String> responseMap = new HashMap <String,String>();

    responseMap.put("crash", 
                    "Well, it never crashes on our system. It must have something\n" +
                    "to do with your system. Tell me more about your configuration.");
    responseMap.put("crashes", 
                    "Well, it never crashes on our system. It must have something\n" +
                    "to do with your system. Tell me more about your configuration.");
    responseMap.put("slow", 
                    "I think this has to do with your hardware. Upgrading your system"); 

    responseMap.put("performance", 
                    "Performance was quite adequate in all our tests. Are you running\n"+
                    "any other processes in the background?");

     responseMap.put("bug", 
                    "Well, you know, all software has some bugs.\n" +
                    "are working very hard to fix them. Can you describe the problem\n" +
                    "further?");

    responseMap.put("windows", 
                    "This is a known bug to do with the Windows operating system.\n"+
                    "report it to Microsoft. There is nothing we can do about this.");
    responseMap.put("mac", 
                    "This is a known bug to do with the Mac operating system. Please\n" +
                    "report it to Apple. There is nothing we can do about this.");
    responseMap.put("expensive", 
                    "The cost of our product is quite competitive. Have you\n" +
                    "really compared our features?");

    responseMap.put("Netbeans", 
                    "Ahhh, BlueJ, yes. We tried to buy out those guys long ago, but\n" +
                    "they simply won't sell... Stubborn people they are. Nothing \n" +
                    "do about it, I'm afraid.");

                    return responseMap;
                            }
```

and the code from the other class

```
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.Random;

  public class Responder
 {
   // Used to map key words to responses.
  private HashMap<String, String> responseMap;
   // Default responses to use if we don't recognise a word.


   private ArrayList<String> defaultResponses;
   private Random randomGenerator;
   private ArrayList<String> uninterestingwords;


  /**
  * Construct a Responder
  */



   public Responder(Response response)
  {
    responseMap = response.createresponseMap();
    defaultResponses = response.CreateDefaultResponse();
    uninterestingwords = response.CreateInterestingWords();
    randomGenerator = new Random();
  }


    /**
    * Generate a response from a given set of input words.
    * 
    * @param words  A set of words entered by the user
   * @return       A string that should be displayed as the response
   */



   public String generateResponse(HashSet<String> words)
   {
    for (String word : words) {


        String responses = responseMap.get(word);

        if(responses != null && uninterestingwords.indexOf(word)>-1) {

            return responses;
        }

    }

    // If we get here, none of the words from the input line was recognized.
    // In this case we pick one of our default responses (what we say when
    // we cannot think of anything else to say...)


    return pickDefaultResponse();
    }


  private String pickDefaultResponse()
  {
    // Pick a random number for the index in the default response list.
    // The number will be between 0 (inclusive) and the size of the list (exclusive).


    int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(defaultResponses.size());
    return defaultResponses.get(index);

  }
  }
```

I'm assuming that there's need to be a change in the method "public String generateResponse(HashSet words)" but what and how?

thanks